# SQL Server stored procedure parameter assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Why can I not use functions to directly assign stored procedure parameters?

e.g.

```
exec myStoredProc @firstParam = aFunctionThatReturnsAnAppropriateValue()
```

but I find I have to decalre a variable just to hold the value

```
declare @temp type = aFunctionThatReturnsAnAppropriateValue()

exec myStoredProc @firstParam = @temp
```

which seems redundant

Comment: It does seem redundant.  So what's your question?

Comment: why can't I do it? I find the syntax in the first code snippet is not accepted by sql server management studio

Comment: It's invalid syntax.  You can't pass a function as argument in an `exec` call.  Only Microsoft can change that.

Comment: so why did you say it was redundant in your first comment? if you can't assign paramter values from functions directly then surely the temp variable is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
Execute a stored procedure or function
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH RECOMPILE ]
    }
[;]
```

You can see that it explicitly says `@variable` or `value`. I guess this is a language limitation, as you can neither write a call to a function as a variable or as a value; it is executable code (an *expression*), and the short-hand assignment during variable declaration is just a misleading bonus.

EDIT: Compare the difference of description for `DECLARE` and `EXECUTE`:

For `DECLARE`

> *=value*
>   Assigns a value to the variable in-line. The value can be a constant **or an expression**, but it must either match the variable
>   declaration type or be implicitly convertible to that type.

When looking through the page for `EXECUTE`, I do not see the mention of an expression. It seems to me that it would be *handy*, as I think you are trying to point out.